# How to resolve "This webpage has a redirect loop" ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Tags: magento2

Kindly assist with my users admin site which previously was displaying There has been an error processing your request - but now the error message when viewed is:
This webpage has a redirect loop
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS
https://www.evoneng.com/store_manager/admin/index/index/key/05b032166f4000205779788af46612659fc16ca2312d94e56482590428dfb534/

Please note the following steps i have already taken.
i) cache/var has been cleaned
ii) the database in the cPanel, the core_config_data table, the values in 
web/unsecure/base_url, and web/secure/base_url are both.
Meanwhile the front page opens.

Please assist what to do

Comment: Are you using Ngnix server?

Comment: Have you check log file of magento as well?

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue after AWS Lightsail snapshot restore. 
Way to restore a snapshot is to click on the three dots on side "create new instance"
Then attach the the static ip.
I observed redirect loops after this. (pain!!!)
Later we  figured out that the redirects was caused by the changes to urls as the base urls changed to IP address.

There are two ways to fix this. 
1. via phpymyadmin > In AWS you need to connect via Putty with Key and tunnel via 8888
https://127.0.0.1:8888/phpmyadmin then 
on  table core_config_data check the base url update base if IP address. 
then change. 
web/secure/use_in_frontend set value from 1 to 0
web/secure/use_in_adminhtml set value from 1 to 0

Then clear magento cache.

2. via cli.

/opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/bin# ./magento-cli cache:flush
Flushed cache types:
config
layout
block_html
collections
reflection
db_ddl
compiled_config
eav
customer_notification
config_integration
config_integration_api
full_page
config_webservice
translate
vertex

mysql> update core_config_data  set value=0 where config_id=115;
 mysql> update core_config_data  set value=0 where config_id=114;

mysql> select * from core_config_data where path like '%web/secure/use_in_frontend%';
+-----------+---------+----------+----------------------------+-------+
| config_id | scope   | scope_id | path                       | value |
+-----------+---------+----------+----------------------------+-------+
|       114 | default |        0 | web/secure/use_in_frontend | 0     |
+-----------+---------+----------+----------------------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from core_config_data where path like '%web/secure/use_in_adminhtml%';
+-----------+---------+----------+-----------------------------+-------+
| config_id | scope   | scope_id | path                        | value |
+-----------+---------+----------+-----------------------------+-------+
|       115 | default |        0 | web/secure/use_in_adminhtml | 0     |
+-----------+---------+----------+-----------------------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

Answer (score 0):

I've recently had the chrome redirect loop on gmail.

Possibly significantly, I was doing some work involving changing my system time and it hasn't worked since. [This guide](https://techshali.com/fix-webpage-has-redirect-loop-error/) helped to do that.

There is an available work-around, which is to use gmail in incognito mode, which does still work, although requires you to log in each time